# android studio gradle erro

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, connection

Android studio 3.0 
in android studio 3.0
 م  Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
at this gardle stops and gives me

Failed to complete grandle excution

Cause:
connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. And make sure your internet is connected.

Comment: Can you explaine more please, i am beginner, where should i write this?

Comment: buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: my android studio is 3.0 vresion preview

Comment: he told me this:               Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: I'll try to send the whole file .. you can replace the content and try..

Comment: can installing gradle offline be useful?

Comment: using other version?

Comment: I installed older version, and it was useful thanks fo helping